# How restart a NodeJS app on Cloud Foundry (after scp'ing code changes)

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, application-restart

I'm attempting to cleanup/fix an existing NodeJS app in IBM's implementation of CloudFoundry.

Doing a full build between changes is killing me so I made a script to SCP changes with the cf ssh-code usage. Here is the script. I found I had to keep getting a code for this op, so I paste it to the clipboard (using clip in Windows). You'd have to just hit paste when prompted for the password:

```
#!/bin/bash

ibmcloud cf ssh-code | sed -n '3 p' > one-time-ssh-code && clip < one-time-ssh-code
scp -P 2222 -o User=cf:<APP GUID>/<INSTANCE NUMBER> $1 <SSH ADDRESS...cloud.ibm.com>:/home/vcap/app/$1

if [[ "$2" == "--restart" ]]
        then
                echo "Restarting Cloud Foundary app..."
                ibmcloud cf restart <APP NAME>
fi
```

For testing I put changes in my app.js for a log to show when the server started up. I pushed those changes in less than a second (much, much faster than doing a build)...

```
$ ./scp-cf app.js
<THE ABOVE CREDENTIALS REFLECTED>'s password:
app.js                                                                                                                                                                100% 4936    32.7KB/s   00:00
```

I ssh into the container:

```
#!/bin/bash

ibmcloud cf ssh-code | sed -n '3 p' > one-time-ssh-code && clip < one-time-ssh-code
ssh cf:<APP GUID>/0@<SSH ADDR>.cloud.ibm.com -p2222
```

I can see that the file was just updated!

Now, I'll run the same `scp-cp app.js` with the `--restart` flag. I thought this would defeat whatever unknowns regarding no node -v or npm, or yarn, on the remote CF app container.

```
app.js                                                                                                                                                                100% 4936    31.7KB/s   00:00
Restarting Cloud Foundary app...
Invoking 'cf restart <APP NAME>
```

I then go look at the file I'd updated before restarting. It is reverted to the file from the last full build...

My point here is that no matter what I can't get the app to pickup changes. I'm only familiar with CF in conjunction with a build pipeline, but I was handed this and I really need to speed up development with the constraints that are upon me.

Can anybody *please* tell me how to actually restart the NodeJS app so that it will pickup changes? I'll post if I figure it out.

EDIT: So, it seems I'm after behaviour that is anti-CF. I still want to do what I'm asking because, unfortunately, I'm working with an existing project with zero tests and I'm in a crunch to fix it - via debugging via logs, remote only.

Could somebody explain why I see node here:

```
vcap@id:~/app$ ps aux | grep node
vcap         140  0.0  0.0   4636   788 ?        S    17:53   0:00 sh -c node app.js
vcap         141  0.3  0.3 1085252 109356 ?      Sl   17:53   0:01 node app.js
vcap         198  0.0  0.0  63336  1104 pts/0    S+   17:59   0:00 grep --color=auto node
```

But, not here:

```
vcap@id:~/app$ node -v
bash: node: command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do a `push` to update what it uses when restarting, restaging, or rescaling.

Test locally.

Comment: 100%. Don't ever update code by using `scp` on Cloud Foundry. Anything you change in this manner will disappear after your app is restarted for *any* reason, not just when you `cf restart`.

Comment: Also, when I ssh into the container I there's no npm, yarn, node -v, none of that. I absolutely cannot test locally. There has to be a way to restart just the running NodeJS app. I totally understand this is NOT an optimal/suggested/good way of doing things. I've no choice about it. I either have to push every change in these 50,000 lines of code where cloud is spelled clod in places, pedal is pedel, label is lebel, etc., or I need to be able to use logs for debugging w/o the 5 minutes between pushing.

Comment: Architecturally, that's not how CF works. Whenever your main node.js/Python/JVM process exits, CF restarts your application using what was last `push`ed.